# jQuery selector for all <img> in a div if class includes a certain string

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, class, dom

I would like to be able to select both of these  with a single css selector:

```
<div id= "someID">
  <img src="images/leave-alone.png" class= "leave-alone">
  <img src= "images/source.png" class= "foo bar">
  <img src= "images/other-source.png" class= "foo zip">
</div>
```

Ideally, something like "class includes 'foo'" to capture both those images at once. I know i can use `.children().last().remove()` twice but I'd like to make sure my code is a bit more dynamic than that.

EDIT: realized I'm doing this on a click, so I'd like to be able to achieve the same thing with `$(this)` as my jQuery starting point.

EDIT: I hacked it with `$("#" + $(this).attr("id") + " img.foo").remove()` but maybe there's something more elegant.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("#someID img.foo")`

Comment: $("#someID img.foo) Or $('img.foo")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this to select all images with `class` foo

```
$("img.foo")
```

Or like this to select images with `class` foo under div with `id` someId

```
$("#someID img.foo")
```

Comment: what if i'm starting with $(this) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try `$('img[class~=foo]')`.

[Advanced selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) are great. This is the source link.